# applying theme to master page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-3.5

I know in general themes cannot be applied to Master pages. But I was wondering there can be some trick or way to do so. In my situation I dont want to apply these to the whole site but only on an application. Because in application there are many pages I cant do it manually. In my situation I am also not able to inherit page class. Any suggestion please. This project is in Asp.net 3.5

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, the only way to do this programmatically if you can't inherit from a base class, is with an HTTP Module.

Check the following blog for an explanation: [Set the Theme for a MasterPage (from code)](http://bloggingabout.net/blogs/rick/archive/2007/10/20/howto-set-the-theme-for-a-masterpage-from-code.aspx)

In your case you should first check the page's master page before you set the page's theme.

Answer (score 0):

You can add this code in Global.asax file:

```
void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object src, EventArgs e)
{
    Page p = this.Context.Handler as Page;
    if (p != null)
    {
        p.PreInit += (s, ev) =>
        {
            DevExpress.Web.ASPxClasses.ASPxWebControl.GlobalTheme = "Aqua";
        };
    }
}
```